# How to add a delete icon functionality for one corner on canvas in fabric js?

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

Generally in fabric js the object has scaling and rotating properties,how to add delete functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i made an example in fiddle to help you with your issue,
but the main points on the code are these :

```
1. which controls we want to see when we select an object
var HideControls = {
            'tl':true, //top left corner is visible
            'tr':false,
            'bl':false,
            'br':false,
            'ml':false,
            'mt':false,
            'mr':false,
            'mb':false,
            'mtr':false
        };


2. a circle object with **only top left corner visible**
 var circle = new fabric.Circle({
                  radius: 20, 
                  fill: 'red', 
                  left: 100, 
                  top: 100
                });
circle.setControlsVisibility(HideControls);
            canvas.add(circle);

3. on mouse:down event we check what we click
canvas.on("mouse:down",function(e){
      var target = canvas.findTarget(e.e);
    console.log('mouse:down');
     //delete object if user clicks on top left corner
    if (target && target.__corner === 'tl') {             
        if (canvas.getActiveObject()) {
            canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject());
        }
    }
});
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/0fbefh52/6/

i create three objects , click on the top left corner to delete tha object.
good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.setControlsVisibility` to turn on/off individual controls:

```
// make just the top-left control visible (active)
yourFabricElement.setControlsVisibility({
    bl: true,
    br: true,
    tl: false,
    tr: true,
    mt: true,
    mb: true,
});
```

Comment: @AmruthaGutta, The `setControlsVisibility` method is explained well here: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#setControlsVisibility. Good luck with your project!